# How can I get Automator to open a URL in the current Safari tab?

Tags: url, applescript, automator

My current code involves a "Watch Me Do" block recording a <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> keystroke and then opening the new URL, but that's kind of kludgy. Is there any way I can use Automator to open a URL within the current tab? AppleScript would also be acceptable.

(Is this question too basic for Stack Overflow?)

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "Safari" to set the URL of the current tab of the front document to "whateverURLYouWant.com"
```

Comment: @nK0de If you're going to edit a post, please make sure that the edit is constructive. For example, please don't change the formatting of a poster's code so you can understand it. Most of the time, we know what we're doing and we wrote it the way we did for a specific reason. Just food for thought. :)

Comment: okay. I thought it was a mistake. sorry about that.

Comment: @nK0de It's all good. :)

Comment: this showed up in the review list. That's why I thought it was wrong. anyway, its cool :)

Comment: That doesn't work for me.
Also, the way you have it formatted makes it impossible to see all of the code; I had to copy and paste it.

Comment: Though actually, nothing of that ilk is working, so I think it may me a bug having to do with my end of things.